# ValueError «You are trying to use the old GPU back-end» when importing keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, theano

I'm using [Keras](https://keras.io/) with the [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/) backend on Ubuntu 16.04. My setup has been working without issues, however, all of a sudden I get the following error when I import Keras (`import keras`):

> ValueError: You are trying to use the old GPU back-end. It was removed from Theano. Use device=cuda* now. See https://github.com/Theano/Theano/wiki/Converting-to-the-new-gpu-back-end%28gpuarray%29 for more information.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: It is probably the environmental variable `THEANO_FLAGS`. If you set the variable so that it contains `device=cuda` instead of `device=gpu` it will be fixed.

Comment: hi @WilmarvanOmmeren, I just tried this now, and it worked. If you put your comment as an answer I will mark it as the correct answer. Thanks .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should change (or add) your environmental variable called `THEANO_FLAGS`. If you set the variable so that it contains `device=cuda` instead of `device=gpu` the error will be gone.

Also set the floating point precision to `float32` when working on the GPU as that is usually much faster (`THEANO_FLAGS='device=cuda,floatX=float32'`).

More info on this variable can be found [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html) and [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html).

Comment: export THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=cuda,floatX=float32

Answer (score 1):

go to .theanorc file and change `device=gpu` to `device=cuda`

Answer (score -2):

for me no gpu,use cpu,work :

```
export THEANO_FLAGS='mode=FAST_RUN,device=cpu,floatX=float32'
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what this means exactly and how it answers the question?